# Replacing text case inside the parentheses

Tags: regex, bulk-rename

For example I have the files with the following names:

```
Apple (Fruit).txt
Palm (Tree).txt
```

How can I transform their names to

```
Apple (fruit).txt
Palm (tree).txt
```

with RegExp using Bulk Rename Utility?

Or without RegExp in case it is not needed to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asked this question at [BRU support forum](https://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=5421) and received two answers:

Using RegEx v2 (tick v2 checkbox under RegEx (1))

```
Match: (\(.*?\))/g
Replace: \L$1
```

and using simple RegEx for BRU 3.4.2.0 and up (tick Simple checkbox under RegEx (1))

```
Match: %1(%2)
Replace: %1(\L%2)
```

Both methods work the same way and do the thing.